# Notepad++ workspace refresh?

Tags: ide, notepad++

How do i refresh the workspace / project in notepad++ when the file-system changes ( files and folders added or removed ).

at the moment it does not keep up with the local file system and i have to re-create the project each time!! frustrating..

Comment: While you can edit source code in notepad++, this has nothing to do with [oop] or [agile].

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I followed Rechtar's suggestion.

I had a similar issue. Notepad++'s Project pane doesn't update when I change or create new files. What I ended up doing was downloading the explorer plugin through

PLUGINS > PLUGIN MANAGER > SHOW PLUGIN MANAGER

Then install the explorer plugin.

After it's installed go to PLUGINS > EXPLORER and select the explorer.

It's not really comparable to something like Eclipse's project navigation.

Comment: Really absurd the need of a plugin for such a basic feature.

Comment: haha... you're right. But hopefully in the next release they will do the enhancement better.

Answer (score 8):

In Notepad++ 7.5.8, this issue has been fixed. I suggest you update your notepad++ to the latest version.

In order to do this, go to **? -> Update Notepad++** and it will automatically detect a new update package. Update Notepad++ normally.

Otherwise, you could download the update from here:
https://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-7.5.8-released.html

In case you're curious, here's the changelog for 7.5.8:

```
    Notepad++ v7.5.8 bug-fixes:

1.  Remove annoying "no update" notification.
2.  Fix Folder as Workspace not updating regression.
3.  Fixed crash issue by checking & unchecking "Disable extension column" option in preferences dialog.
4.  Fixed a crash when trying to launch a secondary instance with command line arguments.
5.  Fix "Explorer Here" from "Folder as Workspace" problem if folder name contains comma.


Included plugins:

1.  NppExport v0.2.8 (32-bit x86 only)
2.  Converter 4.2.1
3.  Mime Tool 2.1
4.  DSpellCheck 1.3.5


Updater (Installer only):

* WinGup (for Notepad++) v5.0.2
```

Comment: not still working in `v7.9.5`

Comment: I have v8.5.3 in the year of our lord 2023 and this is not working for me, when the folder becomes empty or is removed, and then added again (like our log folder, during uninstall - install cycle) it just doesn't refresh and I have to open the folder again as a workspace to get it to show me the files in it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently running version 6.3.3 of notepad ++ and instead of adding the entire project all over again, you can right-click the folder in your project that has the new file and choose: "Add files...". From there, you can select your new file and open it. This will add it to your project in the appropriate folder.

Comment: A good solution, although i have since switched to Sublime text 2. I will say it is really really really reeeallly allot better.

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan I think which you like best is a preference, as they are almost identical in feature sets. I recently saw a poll and Notepad++ beat Sublime Text 2. I have used both extensively and personally prefer Notepad++, but I can see why some people would prefer Sublime Text 2. I think everyone should try both and see which they like best.

Comment: That works, but it's not exactly convenient, particularly if the file is in a folder outside the default. The point is that Notepad++ should see the new files and optionally add them automatically.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a proper way to do this in Notepad++. The Project panel was born just 2 or 3 releases ago, so it's naturally immature. I suggest that you install either the Explorer plugin or the Light Explorer plugin - they are much more usable.

Or better yet, go learn Vim and fall in love with the NERDTree ;-)